# Como evitar el resubmit de formulario al refrescar la pagina en django

Tags: django

buenas estoy haciendo una pequeña app de notas al guardar el formulario el views.py me devuelve a la misma pagina hasta hay todo bien, pero cuando actualizo la pagina me aparece un mensaje diciendo que el formulario sera enviado nueva mente

```
def guardar(request):
        notas = noteblock.objects.all()

        note = formularionotes(request.POST)
        if note.is_valid():
            note.save()
            return render(request,'notes.html',{'notas':notas})
```

alquien porfavor me explica como hago que esto no pase

Answer (score 0):

En este caso tienes que añadir un return HttpResponseRedirect. Para mayor información puede ir a  [primeros pasos con Django parte 4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial04/)  y ir a la sección donde se modifica views.py.

En esta parte mencionan que siempre se debe retornar un HttpResponseRedirect después de manejar los datos con el POST, y esto se hace para evitar que se envíen dos veces los datos.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Este link da ejemplos del uso de HttpResponseRedirect [enlace](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial04/) y este es la documentación que provee Django [enlace](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect)

Answer (score 0):

Yo haria esto.

En el **modelo**.

```
Class noteblock(models.Model):
    ....

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Return absolute url for a noteblock."""
        return reverse('noteblock',
                       args=[self.slug])
```

En La **vista**.

```
def guardar(request):
    notas = noteblock.objects.all()

    note = formularionotes(request.POST)
    if note.is_valid():
        note.save()
        return redirect(note.get_absolute_url())
```